# Why does Spock's rapid aging stop after Genesis?

Tags: star-trek, spock

In *The Search for Spock*, Spock is resurrected as a consequence of <strike>super blood</strike> the Genesis effect.  A new organism, genetical identically to the deceased Spock, is created from the DNA in his corpse, which was left on the planet Genesis at the end of *The Wrath of Khan*.

On Genesis, the new Spock ages more rapidly than normal, going from infancy to adulthood in the space of a day or two.  By the time he is rescued from Genesis by Kirk and friends, he seems to be at roughly the same age as when he died (albeit somewhat conveniently).

My question:

**Why did Spock stop aging so rapidly when he was removed from Genesis?  (If the answer is that one must be present on Genesis to experience the effect, then why did it not not affect David Marcus or Saavik?)  Also, when Spock was removed from Genesis, was he younger, the same age, or older than when he died?**

Comment: Nimoy radiation caused him to stop aging at the exact age of the actor that plays him. Seriously, I don't have a canon answer for this but I would hazard to guess that his (new) body absorbed and or continued to absorb a certain amount of energy/radiation from the Genesis device/effect. Once he was removed from the source of the energy, any leftover energy dissipated quickly and his aging slowed to normal. As for the others, they were already alive. The Genesis device brought life to a dead world and a dead Spock but didn't have (much) effect on the living.

Comment: Sometimes a plot hole is just a plot hole.

Comment: "If the answer is that one must be present on Genesis to experience the effect, then why did it not not affect David Marcus or Saavik?" - because neither of them were resurrected?

Comment: Because literal dues ex machina

Comment: @Richard I agree.  Voted to close.

Comment: @KyleJones - I wanted a second opinion before dropping the dupehammer :-)

Comment: In addition to the question being highly similar, [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9805/20774) makes direct reference to Spock's aging process and offers several convincing theories. If you don't like that answer, the appropriate thing to do is to either make a comment (in the hopes that the answerer will expand on their answer), post a bounty to request additional info or research and answer the question yourself.